# Spring data mongodb config

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, spring-cloud-config

I have a spring boot application, using spring-data-mongodb. 
With the following MongoDB config in `application.properties`, the mongoRepository read/write documents into the correct database: `product_db`. Everything is correct so far.

```
#MongoDB Config
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=product_db
spring.data.mongodb.username=demo
spring.data.mongodb.password=demo
spring.data.mongodb.database=product_db
```

Then I introduced spring-cloud-config, and I moved the **exact same MongoDB config** to `my-service.properties`so the config client can get these from config server. The weird thing is that now mongoRepository read/write document from/into database: `test`

Where does spring-cloud-config-server specific the database name? How to config to ask mongoRepository to use the correct database?

Code snippet as following
Config Server

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableConfigServer
public class ConfigServiceApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

application.properties for config server

```
server.port=2000
spring.application.name=config-server
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8260/eureka

spring.profiles.active=native
spring.cloud.config.server.native.search-locations=file:///${user.home}/Project/configuration
```

my-test.properties

```
server.port=2100
spring.application.name=service-sample
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8260/eureka
logging.level.org.springframework=INFO

#MongoDB Config
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=product_db
spring.data.mongodb.username=demo
spring.data.mongodb.password=demo
spring.data.mongodb.database=product_db
```

For my-service as the config client:

```
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "com.mydemo.service.sample.repositories")
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

bootstrap.properties for config client:

```
server.port=2100
spring.application.name=my-service

eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8260/eureka

spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled=true
spring.cloud.config.discovery.service-id=config-server
```

As mentioned before, if I remove the bootstrap.properties, and use the following application.properties file for my-service, everything is good.

```
server.port=2100
spring.application.name=service-sample    
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8260/eureka    
logging.level.org.springframework=INFO

#MongoDB Config
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=product_db
spring.data.mongodb.username=demo
spring.data.mongodb.password=demo
spring.data.mongodb.database=product_db
```

Comment: paste the code how you import my-service.properties

Comment: @clevertension provided related code in the question. Hope it helps

Comment: Problem solved. The config client did not include the "spring-cloud-starter-config" and did not specify the "spring.cloud.config.profile". Without the correct config, it is using the default mongoDB config, which uses "test" database.